# Transposing on a Directed Graph

Tags: java

I've been assigned the following problem, but am having issues figuring it out. I know what I'd like to accomplish, but given the skeleton code he's outlined for us, I'm not sure where to start...I drew a pic to illustrate what I'd like to accomplish (I think...)

http://i802.photobucket.com/albums/yy304/Growler2009/Transposing-1.jpg

**This is what I need to do:**

Consider a directed graph G(V;A). The transpose of G written GT (V;AT ) is nothing more than
G where all the arcs have been transposed, i.e., the origin of the arc becomes the end and the end
becomes the origin. In a sense, GT is the \backward" version of G. For this question you must
implement an algorithm which, given a directed graph, produces its transpose. The API of the
algorithm is given by the following interface:

```
public interface Transpose<VT,AT> {
public DIGraph<VT,AT> doIt(DIGraph<VT,AT> src);
}
```

Implement the transpose algorithm given above. You have no restrictions on how to do this (except
that it must operate on a graph represented as an adjacency list and it cannot modify the original
graph. Report (in the comments) the space and time complexities in big O notation and brie
y
justify. (i.e., how long does it take and how much space does it uses to transpose a graph with n
vertices and m arcs).

Any help you can offer to get me started would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: fair to assume this is homework?

Comment: Do you have a class to represent the directed graph already?  If not, how would you design one?  What are the 'things' in a directed graph?

Comment: @phatmanace: Yes, this is a homework assignment. I've been doing a lot of reading to get it done, but it's not working out... Am I not allowed to ask hw questions?

Comment: @Tony: I've already written a class (MyDiGraph) for the directed graph... which makes use of 2 other classes I've written: MyArc and MyVertex...  MyDiGraph has a bunch of methods to check for adjacency, insertArc and insertVertex... I haven't finished OutGoing and Incoming methods yet, however...

Comment: @Growler, the drawing is very good and especially the arrows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pseudolanguagecode:

```
create new empty set of edges E
for I in all edges:
    (X,Y) = vertices of edge I ;
    insert edge (Y,X) to E;
result is in E.
```

Space complexity: no requirements

Time complexity: O(num. of edges)

Comment: Can you please expand upon your answer?

Comment: Can you please expand upon your answer?  I was thinking along the lines of doing this for transpose: I've written the following methods for my MyDirectedGraph class (which Transpose class uses as its constructor): opposite(vertex, arc); endVertices(arc); areAdjacent(vertex1, vertex2); update for MyVertex and MyArc(used to update their data); insert Vertex and Arc; iterable methods for  both incoming and outgoing vertices. So... shouldnt I Get an arc's beginning vertex... call areAdjacent method... if yes, call endVertices~ determine which is origin.. then swap it with the other vertex?